Expect script: "send" command loses first character?
I have a script which connects me to VPN using GlobalProtect:
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn globalprotect connect -p my.server.com
expect "username:"
send "JoeDoe\r"
expect "Password:"
send "joespassword\r"
interact

To run the script, do > expect script_name.exp
I've used the script for weeks now. However, it suddenly started failing. The server side started getting "oeDoe" as username - the first character is missing.
What could have happened?

Has the program's output changed? Have the prompts changed? What does expect -d script_name.exp report around the username prompt?

try adding sleep 1 before send.

@sexpect-ExpectforShells Tried sleep 3, didn't help.

If you change it to send "1JoeDoe\r" it works?

what happens if you try the following?
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn globalprotect connect -p my.server.com -u JoeDoe
expect "Password:"
send "joespassword\r"
interact

